# With psql, how to make output of '\d {tableName}' remain in console?

Tags: postgresql, psql

On Ubuntu, running psql from command line, when I type in '\d {tableName}' it takes me to some viewer mode similar to vi where I have to then hit 'q' to go back. Then I lose the list of columns that I was just seeing and am back to the console.

Is there some way to have it like it is on CentOS where the output of 
'\d {tableName}' is a simple query that writes output onto the console and stays there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on [pager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144016/what-is-a-pager) configuration. You should to check content of `PAGER` variable.

```
set | grep PAGER
```

If you use a [`pspg`](https://github.com/okbob/pspg) pager, then a option `-X` disables returning original content of display when the pager is ended. Same option has a pager `less`.

One of good configuration for `less` pager can be

```
export PAGER="less"
export LESS="-iMSx4 -FX"
```

Answer (score 1):

That viewer mode is called a **pager**.

You can disable it in the psql shell with

```
\pset pager off
```

or when starting psql by passing the `pset` flag:

```
psql --pset pager=off
```

`pset` is used to specify printing options. See the [docs on psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) for more.